# How to roll back used functions in a web service? should I use transaction?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm developing a web application that connects to a web service.
web service gives me two separate functions but they are related each other.
`RegisterWorker` function register a worker and generate a code for him/her.
`InsertWorkerInformation` function, Inserts some worker information in data base according to generated code.

```
function int RegisterWorker(parameters)
{
  return Genereated worker code;
} 

function int InsertWorkerInformation(int generated worker code)
{
   return 1;//If Success Insert information in DB
   return 0;//If fails
}
```

My web application receives required information which is filled by user and the first calls the `RegisterWorker` function and then calls the `InsertWorkerInformation` function.

```
int code=RegisterWorker(parameters)
InsertWorkerInformation(code)
```

the second function absolutely must run after first function.
I want to know what can I do if the first function executes properly but the second function doesn't execute properly.(maybe losing connection between web application and web service and etc)
how can I roll back the first function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you don't.  A normal webservice is a type of disconnected model. There's no transactions around multiple webservice calls.

If you have access to the code of this webservice, it may make sense to create a web method that performs both actions in one call, and it internally uses a transaction.

Alternatively, is there an 'UnRegisterWorker'?  If so, that could be in your catch block to 'fake' a rollback.