# Are there any transactions around multiple webservice calls?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Are there any transactions around multiple webservice calls.
Let me start with a commonly used example -- the travel agency. A customer intends to create a travel plan through an online travel agency. To do this, the online travel application calls the following three Web services:

```
-Air ticket booking
  -Hotel reservation
  -Taxi reservation
```

These three services are available from three separate vendors. If any one of these three services fails, the customer does not wish to proceed with the transaction (again, either all three services must succeed or none at all).
My language programming is Asp.net c#.
what's the solution?

Comment: This is a certain problem, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Transactions cannot go past web service boundaries.

Comment: What can i do in these situations?

Comment: @Raymond Morphy - Rethink your design so it doesn't depend on all three succeeding, using retries and statuses.

Comment: so what is your opinion about this post? [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504943/how-roll-back-used-functions-in-a-web-service-should-i-use-transaction)

Comment: @Raymond Morphy - I think the answer from Brian nailed it. If you need transactional support, do it _within_ a single service call.

Comment: thanks for your answers Oded. could you give me your Idea about this website description too? [link] (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-transws/)

Comment: @Raymond Morphy - I am not familiar with WS-T and WS-C. If all webservices support these protocols, then you might be able to use them with transactions. However, it is my experience that if the platforms are not from the same vendor, there will be compatibility issues.

Comment: @Oded: I have to downvote you on this. The fact is that transactions can work _if the services in question support them_. That's just the same as saying that reliable messaging or encryption only work if the services in question support them.

Answer (score 1):

Raymond,
Have you ruled out WS-AT? [Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729784.aspx)

You'll need some form of two-phase commit capability from the other service providers.

Other than that, you'll need a compensating transaction approach.