# Are there any transactions around multiple webservice calls?

Tags: asp.net, transactions

A few days ago I asked this question in stackoverflow and ASP.net forums.
the answer which I got was "No, this is not possible. Transactions cannot go past web service boundaries"
[Are there any transactions around multiple webservice calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505096/are-there-any-transactions-around-multiple-webservice-calls)

but in ASP.net forum I got the answer below:
http://jalpesh.blogspot.com/2010/05/using-transactions-with-linq-to-sql.html
 it's offering `system.transaction`.
what is your suggestion about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any transactions around
>   multiple webservice calls?

The answer to the above question is that in the general case **it is possible** to have disparate web services participate in the same transaction.  To do this you would use the industry standard [WS-Transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Transaction) which is part of the [WS-Coordination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Coordination) specification. The specification of interest is [WS-Atomic Transaction (WSAT)](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-tx/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec-os/wstx-wsat-1.2-spec-os.html).

If you are running on a Microsoft stack and have MSDTC configured properly between all machines then it is possible to pass transactions between web services (see [Propagating a Transaction Across AppDomains](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2010/04/30/propagating-a-transaction-across-appdomains.aspx).

So, the answer is yes, it is possible in general.  However, if you are talking about incorporating transactions around arbitrary third party services (as your previous question appears to be about) then that is **probably** not possible because most likely those third party services do not support WSAT (and I don't blame them!).

Unfortunately, in these scenarios, the best you can hope for in the event of failure is to execute compensating actions.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL really has nothing to do with transactions around web service calls.

I remember reading about this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Transaction but have no idea of the state of any of the implementations.  So I won't say it can't be done, but if it is possible, based on the companies involved in the spec, it will be very expensive and very complex.